# ¿ Como guardo el color de un boton que envia un comando python por php?

Tags: php, javascript, python, web

Buenas tardes,

tengo una duda, estoy haciendo un servidor web en la raspberry pi, y cuando me conecto por el navegador tengo diversos botones que actúan sobre las salidas del GPIO con python y con form=post de php

Como puedo hacer para que una vez pulse un botón cambie de color y se quede de color hasta que pulse otros botones que yo decida (estos tendrán unas ID's especificas)

quizás tenga que dar más explicaciones, espero que alguien lo lea y me pueda ayudar porque no lo consigo.

```
function setColor(btn, color){
    var count=1;
    var property = document.getElementById(btn);
    var red = 3
    if (count == 0){
        property.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
        count=1;
    }
    else{
        property.style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00"
        count=0;
    }

}
```

con este script consigo que cambie por un momento pero creo que cuando se ejecuta el *.py vuelve a cambiar de color y se pone de nuevo en su estado.